# Does useContext/useSelector affect performance, compared with passing through attributes?

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]

I have a component which contains several nested child components; these children require information about the parent component, as well as data from my redux store. Given their quantity, is it better performance wise to use the useSelector hook once within the parent component and pass it down through attributes (rather than context), than it is to have each child use useSelector? Additionally, is it better to pass information about the parent component through its attributes, than it is to have each child use useContext?

edit: in testing, there is a 20% increase in speed when passing through attributes; my guess is useSelector/useContext is more costly in its declaration than an attribute? Can anyone confirm this to be true?

Comment: It's too bad this did not get answered this is a great question

Answer (score 0):

> is it better performance wise to use the useSelector hook once within
> the parent component and pass it down through attributes (rather than
> context), than it is to have each child use useSelector?

The second one is a better choice. You will have less unnecessary re-renders compare to the first choice.

In your first choice scenario, when something in the parent is changed, it will trigger the re-render for the component (means, the children will be affected).

> is it better to pass information about the parent component through
> its attributes, than it is to have each child use useContext?

The answer is same with the above.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `react-redux` uses context API
https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/search?q=useContext&unscoped_q=useContext

In terms of performance, all the above approaches are close to each over.

The best way to deal with performance issues is the following:

1. Wite good-quality code (number of args per function, number of lines per module, cyclomatic complexity, block nesting, fan-in/fan-out coefficients and so far and so on). Do not take into account performance issues.
2. Profile and find out bottlenecks in your good quality code. Prioritize them.
3. Fix found issues https://en.reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html

Comment: React-Redux does use the Context API internally, but [it uses context to pass _the store instance for subscriptions_, not _the current state value](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/01/blogged-answers-react-redux-and-context-behavior/).  This results in [_very_ different performance behavior than `useContext` does](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#context-and-rendering-behavior).

Comment: `const [contextValue, setContextValue] = useState({a: 1, b: 2});`
this is just an example of misusage of Context API. Context API could be used more efficient.
https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats
In case of multiple fields:
https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consuming-multiple-contexts